# How can i get only the value of public key from that method

Tags: java

Key Generation Method

```
public static String generateKeys(String keyAlgorithm, int numBits) {

    try {
        // Get the public/private key pair
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
        keyGen.initialize(numBits);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

         System.out.println("\n" + "Generating key/value pair using " + privateKey.getAlgorithm() + " algorithm");

        // Get the bytes of the public and private keys
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();

        // Get the formats of the encoded bytes
        String formatPrivate = privateKey.getFormat(); // PKCS#8
        String formatPublic = publicKey.getFormat(); // X.509

        String pv=String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes);

        System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(pv));

        String pb=String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes);
        System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(pb));
           //  return pb;

            // System.out.println("Private Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(privateKeyBytes)));
            // System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes)));

        // The bytes can be converted back to public and private key objects
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyAlgorithm);
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        PrivateKey privateKey2 = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyBytes);
        PublicKey publicKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        // The original and new keys are the same
            // System.out.println("  Are both private keys equal? " + privateKey.equals(privateKey2));
            // System.out.println("  Are both public keys equal? " + publicKey.equals(publicKey2));
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException specException) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        System.out.println("Invalid Key Spec Exception");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        System.out.println("No such algorithm: " + keyAlgorithm);
    }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my Key Generation Code
I want to get only the value of Public Key from the above method and send it to the server using serialization.

```
 String pb=String.valueOf(publicKeyBytes);
 System.out.println("Public Key : " + Base64.encode(pb));
```

But my method show null 
How can i store public/private key in a file via key store library or any other method

Comment: You have to be more specific on your tags. Is this on cryptography?

Comment: please be more specific. is this just about how to get it into a file? so a pure IO problem? or is there more to it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but your `generateKeys()` method always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the public key string by running the following:

System.out.println(new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(publicKeyBytes)));